# ruby hash check if value exists

Tags: ruby, hash

Must be an easy question.. but I can't seem to find the answer.
I'm trying to check if a value exists for a specific key within hash.

```
hash = {{"name" => "John", "Loc" => "US", "fname" => "John Doe"},
        {"name" => "Eve", "Loc" => "UK", "fname" => "John Eve"}}
```

Currently I am looping through hash, to check for `if h["name"] = "John"...`

I was looking to see if  a `.include` or `.has_value?` type of approach is available. I read the documentation on hash and a book I have on hand but couldn't find it.

I thought something like `if hash["name"].has_value?("John")` be most useful than looping through hash. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If it would be useful to to determine which elements of the array of hashes (say, `arr`), contain `"name"=>"John"`, you could do this: `arr.size.times.select { |i| arr[i]["name"] == "John" }`. This returns a (possibly empty) array of indices of `arr` that correspond to matching hashes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all our hash is not a valid hash. I suppose you want to have an array of hashes like this

```
array = [
  { "name" => "John", "Loc" => "US", "fname" => "John Doe" },
  { "name" => "Eve",  "Loc" => "UK", "fname" => "John Eve" }
]
```

then you can do something like this:

```
array.select { |hash| hash['name'] == 'John' }
# => returns [{"name" => "John", "Loc" => "US", "fname" => "John Doe"}] 

array.any? { |hash| hash['name'] == 'John' }
# => true
```

Comment: Why use `.include?` instead of `==` ? Is there an advantage over `array.select { |hash| hash['name'] == 'John' }`, which seems simpler?